# How can we check matching data from two loop in jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have two loops in my funtionality. One is forloop and other one is $.each(). I need to compare two loop and if there is matching data check box show as selected ="selected". Please check my code and correct me.

```
var cssClassRel      = event.other.cssClass; //class-7b,class-7c,class-10c etc 
var cssClassRelSplit = cssClassRel.split(" ");
var cssFor = [];
var cssEach = [];
for(var i=0; i<cssClassRelSplit.length; i++){
  cssFor = cssClassRelSplit[i]
}
$('div.saveFilter').find('input:checkbox').each(function () {
   cssEach = $(this).attr('rel') ////class-7b,class-7c,class-10c,class-10d,class-12c etc
   if(cssFor == cssEach){
     $(this).prop('checked', true);
   } 
   else{
     $(this).prop('checked', false);
   }
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="p-t-15 saveFilter">
     <div class="col-sm-3">
        <label class="labeling"><input type="checkbox" rel="class-7b" class="cssData" checked=""/> 7b</label>
      </div>
     <div class="col-sm-3">
        <label class="labeling"><input type="checkbox" rel="class-7c" class="cssData" checked=""/> 7c</label>
     </div>
     <div class="col-sm-3">
         <label class="labeling"><input type="checkbox" rel="class-10c" class="cssData" checked=""/> 10c</label>
     </div>
     .....
     .....
     .....
</div>
```

Comment: jQuery provided an inArray function https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/)

Comment: Shouldn't you have your for loop inside the each loop?

Comment: Side-note: I hate long-hand boolean checks... reduce those 6 lines to `$(this).prop('checked', cssFor == cssEach);` :)

Comment: You should be able to simply find the target elements using information from your array, rather than search them all each time. Can you provide a sample of the HTML as well?

Comment: @GoneCoding. I have added HTML in my question. Thanks

Comment: Your outer code is missing. Does it belong in a click/change/custom-event handler? your `.other` is causing me problems :)

Comment: @BobGilmore No! Code Review is not a debugging service. Aside from that, it's stripped from it's context and would make a lousy question at Code Review. Please take a look at their [help centre](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`prop` can have a callback function instead of a value, `split` returns an array which has its own indexOf method. Combining those 2, the entire set can be written as:

```
$('div.saveFilter input:checkbox').prop('checked', function(){return cssClassRelSplit.indexOf($(this).attr('rel')) !== -1;});
```

Complete example based on your html (assuming the input for cssClassRel is a string):

```js
var cssClassRel      = 'class-7b class-7c class-10c'
var cssClassRelSplit = cssClassRel.split(" ");

$('div.saveFilter input:checkbox').prop('checked', function(){return cssClassRel.indexOf($(this).attr('rel')) !== -1;});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="p-t-15 saveFilter">
     <div class="col-sm-3">
        <label class="labeling"><input type="checkbox" rel="class-7b" class="cssData" checked=""/> 7b</label>
      </div>
     <div class="col-sm-3">
        <label class="labeling"><input type="checkbox" rel="class-7c" class="cssData" checked=""/> 7c</label>
     </div>
     <div class="col-sm-3">
         <label class="labeling"><input type="checkbox" rel="class-10c" class="cssData" checked=""/> 10c</label>
     </div>   
     <div class="col-sm-3">
         <label class="labeling"><input type="checkbox" rel="NotInArray" class="cssData" checked=""/> Not in array</label>
     </div>   
</div>
```

Comment: Great. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Use `inArray` like Julian said and combine with `side-note` Gone Coding.

The result is like this : https://jsfiddle.net/synz/huqjqxpa/
:)